# Array to string errors on hook_views_data()

Tags: 7, views, hooks

Why do I get these errors/notices on my `hook_views_data()` implementations?

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in format_string() (line 1550 of C:\wamp\vhosts\mydrupal72\includes\bootstrap.inc).
```

(4 instances) on defining

```
$data['mytable']['table']['group'] = t('Group name');
```

and:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in views_ui_edit_page_title() (line 273 of C:\wamp\vhosts\mydrupal72\sites\all\modules\views\views_ui.module).
```

(4 instances too) on defining:

```
$data['mytable']['table']['base'] = array('field' => 'field_id', 'title' => t('title'));
```

Comment: What do you get if you dpm($data['mytable']['table']['group'])?

Comment: `dpm($data['mytable']['table']['group']);` gets string: `'Group name'` like I expect to. Also calling `dpm($data['mytable']['table']['base']);` gets me an `array('field' => 'field_id', 'title' => 'title')` also as expected.

Comment: Right. Try to call the dpm before your line of code defining it, to see what it was before you set it to "Group Name". From the error looks like views is expecting an array, not a string

Comment: From your response it seems you were expecting that this implementation is of `hook_views_data_alter(&$data);` Following that cue, I'd since implemented this hook instead of `hook_views_data()` and this error/notice has disappeared. I wonder why `hook_views_data()` doesn't work but `hook_views_data_alter(&$data)` does. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, you should be changing data using the alter. views_data just gives you the views structure, doesn't change it. As you can see in [hook_views_data_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data_alter/7.x-3.x): "Alter table structure. You can add/edit/remove existing tables defined by hook_views_data().